# The ngIf condition in component template error?

Tags: angular

I get this error in component `BlockComponent`:

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of
> 'app-adresat-list'.

Component `BlockComponent` has template:

```
<app-adresat-list *ngIf="element.tag === 'ADRESATS'" [parentBlock]="parentBlock" [list]="element?.children"></app-adresat-list>
```

Why `*ngIf` does not work on component, it happens sometimes, not always?

I have checked that `BlockComponent` registered in app.module.

I have tried to replace templte on this:

```
<div *ngIf="true">Done</div>
```

It works, why?

All code is:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of documentBlock?.children">
    <ng-container *ngIf="element.type === fielType.Block">
        <app-block [parentBlock]="documentBlock?.children" [element]="element"></app-block>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: have you imported *CommonModule* in your *ngModule*?

Comment: Sure, I know about it, maybe problem is that I use template  of `BlockComponent` recursive ?

Comment: Can you put some more code? Is element.tag has the correct value?

Comment: Yes, has correct code. Now it works sometimes no,  I have posted all code

Comment: If the component is from 3rd party lib it's not your fault, if it's yours make sure your import `CommonMdoule` in the same module the component is imported in

Comment: I have checked, all components are registered in app.module where is present commonModule

Comment: All component is my own components

Comment: Could it be reason of `WARNING in Circular dependency detected:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please import CommonModule from the module that is providing your component.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 



@NgModule(
{ imports: [CommonModule], 
declarations: [MyComponent]
 ... })

 class MyComponentModule {}
```